where the pedal does not let up

'We’re looking forward to spreading this new lust for life we have,’ he told Rolling Stone, doing his best to sound confident. ‘There’s a new strength in Metallica that’s never been there before. There are still fearful parts, too. But I’m pretty well set up. And I’m really proud of the new music. I think we did something where the pedal does not let up.’

Could you please explain the meaning of this idiom?

It might not be an idiom.  He might be referring to the pedal of the kick drum.  But it is difficult to say without more context.

It's a heavy metal music context. He's alluding to pedal to the metal (press the accelerator pedal hard down on the metal floor of the car) - full belt, thrashing it.
It reminds me of Spinal Tap with the amp that goes to volume 11 - full volume, full pace, full bore, flat out.

Thanks, and to  LET UP A PEDAL means to stop accelerating?

In this context, that's what he means. But don't bother learning it, and certainly don't make any attempt to use it yourself! The only thing you might usefully learn here is the actual idiom I linked to - [put the] pedal to the metal. In all the 10s of millions of books indexed by Google, the only instance of the sequence "the pedal does not let up" is the text you're asking about!

@VladVintskevich - The meaning is kind of fuzzy.  Do not expect to see masterful, grammar-book-perfect English prose in what a guy in Metallica says to a music journalist.

@VladVintskevich You have the correct idea, but the phrasing "let up a pedal" is not common/idiomatic.  In American English a more idiomatic way to say that would be "let up on the gas" or "ease up on the gas"; both of which mean to reduce pressure on the accelerator pedal (and thus reduce the rate of gasoline flowing to the engine).

@DotCounter: But despite Michael's low opinion of the source, the speaker obviously knows that there's a certain "consistency" (and alliteration) in a member of a band called Metallica alluding to pedal to the metal. Stepping on or easing up on the gas would just be weird in the exact context.

@MichaelHarvey Is it? I don't see any unclarity.

@FumbleFingers Yes, of course; my point was merely in specific relation to OP's "let up a pedal" wording above.  I am not in any way arguing against the fact that the quote is alluding to the "pedal to the medal" idiom.

@DotCounter Note, it doesn't say "let up a pedal" (pedal is the object); it says "the pedal doesn't let up" (pedal is subject)

@AndyBonner Read OP's first comment under this answer to see what "let up a pedal" is in relation to.

@AndyBonner - I was alluding to what you have now made explicit - the quoted text says 'something where the pedal does not let up', which might allude to a situation where the pedal does not come back up when you take your foot off it (like a scary runaway car), which is not very idiomatic, or maybe it could be clumsy speaking where the speaker means 'the band or player does not let up on the pedal' or it could mean neither. It's rock-speak. Like I wrote, 'fuzzy'.

@DotCounter: The point is that idiomatic usages such as (put the) pedal to the metal aren't usually "productive" in  the sense of being amenable to superficially natural rephrasing. Check out this chart comparing put the pedal to the and take the pedal off the. NGrams limits us to 5 words in a search term, but for the first one, almost all matches will be followed by metal. And almost none of the (few) second.

I think the most likely explanation is that Hetfield deliberately used poor phrasing to create a short, punchy sentence.
Hetfield is drawing from the common idiom 'pedal to the metal', which as @FumbleFingers says is a reference to pushing the accelerator pedal all the way to the floor and figuratively going all out.
To 'let up' means to relent (and this is reinforced here because you literally let up an accelerator pedal). He should have said that the band doesn't let up; this is a fairly common type of mistake, where the grammar is fine and the sentence looks logical at first glance but the subjects are mixed up. However, there's no nice way of rephrasing this that I can see; you either have to change the metaphor or make the sentence much longer and more complex.
I think this is the most likely explanation, but @stangdon's comment that he might be referring to the pedal of the kick drum and literally saying that the drum beat is unrelenting is possible. I'd love to see an answer or comment from a major Metallica fan about whether that or another music-based explanation is plausible.

Electric guitars also have pedals that control the amplifier.

"Poor phrasing"/"mistake"? It's just a metaphor, and it's an idiomatically common one, in other contexts as well as music (business, etc.) Meanwhile, bringing literal drum or guitar pedals in just confuses the OP; there is zero chance that the passage discusses them. (For one thing, a kick pedal that "doesn't let up" would be a very limited musical usefulness!)

@Andy Bonner 'Pedal to the metal' and 'let up' are commonly used; mashing them together into 'the pedal does not let up' is certainly not common, and as I said makes the pedal the active party when it logically should be the one being let up. And this is a common type of mistake; it's very easy to mix up the subject and object in a sentence, especially if you're doing something complex like mixing metaphors.
I'd really like to hear a fuller explanation of why you think there's zero chance Hetfield was referring to something musical in that sentence.

@aantia Why it's likely not a literal musical pedal: The context, first of all. All other sentences in that paragraph are talking about the band's attitude and levels of confidence and assertiveness. It would be odd to say "We're strong, we're vivacious, we're prepared, we're accomplished, and we used a lot of hi-hat." Another is that, if a literal pedal (kick, hi-hat, or guitar effect) were intended, the context doesn't identify which one and, unlike the metaphorical car pedal, it would need to. And of course the biggest is that it would be an odd way of talking about these musical pedals...

... If you depress a kick drum pedal and don't let up, you get a single kick. If you do the same for the hi-hat, you can play the closed hi-hat all day, but that would be musically odd (and not exactly useful to Metallica's sound). Most guitar effects pedals are switches; I think they take effect as soon as they're depressed, but keeping it depressed would have no different effect than releasing the switch. Variable pedals like wah are normally manipulated and not simply left at one position. A volume pedal could make sense, but that's about the only one, and again it's not understood as...

... as "THE" pedal, without further clarification. Now, my objections to these pedals "not letting up" could be dismissed: you could say that "the kick drum pedal doesn't let up" to mean simply "is unrelenting," or as hyperbole "is applied so much that it's as if it never lets up." But I come back to the fact that no musical pedal has been identified, and to the fact that it doesn't fit with the other sentences in the paragraph.

Meanwhile, I still assert that the usage is reasonable, clear, and doesn't need revision. This pattern of speech happens often: in which an inanimate object, which is acted upon, is spoken of as if it's actually the agent of the action. It's common with vehicles: "The car didn't even apply the brakes before the accident" (really means "the driver of the car didn't apply the brakes"). Or "the house sold for more than the asking price" (the owners sold it), or etc. In "the pedal doesn't let up" there aren't even mixed metaphors. There's been a lot of talk on this page about...

... about the phrase "pedal to the metal." It's popular in the context of metal music, for including the word "metal," but it's not the only way that the metaphor of a gas pedal is used. Cars' pedals are often used in other constructions; business-speak is fond of "pump the brakes"; the phrase "floor it" is an idiom. He could have said "we stomped the pedal down and never let up," and it wouldn't count as an allusion to the phrase "pedal to the metal," just as a parallel use of an accelerator metaphor. And I maintain that making the pedal itself a subject is reasonable and idiomatic.

Consider the following:

"We put the pedal to the metal and we never let up off the gas."

The above sentence combines two car-related idioms: "put the pedal to the metal", and "let up off the gas".
put the pedal to the metal - describes pushing a car's accelerator pedal as far as it will go (i.e. all the way to the metal floors - which is also were the equivalent "floor it" idiom comes from).  This can typically be used to mean "go fast" or "go as fast as possible" or "go as intensely as possible".
let up off the gas - describes reducing the pressure held to a car's accelerator pedal (which implies reducing the acceleration and/or speed of the car). This will typically be used to mean "slow down".
Combined, the two idioms play off the same concept and strengthen one another:

"We (go as fast as possible) and (we never slow down)."


Back to the quotation:

"...I think we did something where the pedal does not let up."

In the article you quoted the speaker does not say either idiom outright, but both are implied.
However, as this is an article about the band Metallica putting out new music, we can assume that this sentence is treating the combined-idiom as a metaphor.
They are playing music with intensity, and that intensity does not diminish.
Or, to say things more idiomatically:

"...I think we (made) something where (we put the pedal to the metal and we never let up)."

